# How do I incorporate a custom control from github to my project and stay up to date

Tags: ios, xcode, git, version-control, github

I use a couple of custom controls from github, thus far I've always added source code files as new resources to my project in XCode. But I have now seen this repo getting updated frequently, it made me wonder if I can add source files and get them updated (manually or automatic) when something new is pushed. Sorry it might be a noob question.

This is the repo : [BlockAlertsAnd-ActionSheets](https://github.com/gpambrozio/BlockAlertsAnd-ActionSheets)

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you want a git submodule.

As far as I know, there's no way to do this within Xcode, so you'd need to do this from the command line.

And if you're comfortable with using git via the Terminal command line, [here's a tutorial on how to get this set up](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules).

Answer (score 1):

you can use [CocoaPods](http://cocoapods.org/). and there is a pod for this [repo](http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/BlockAlertsAnd-ActionSheets/1.0.4/).
it's really useful to manage your dependencies. to get a new version of a pod, you'll need just update your Podfile and run 'pod install'. Check the website, you'll find more info there.

Comment: this looks like an easier approach. but I just noticed the repo uses non-ARC code. thanks anyway, i might use it later